# Chat just took a dive, everything operational or are we headed for bad news?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

Chat just took a dive, everything operational or are we headed for bad news?

https://chat.stackoverflow.com is "[not loading](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/chat.stackexchange.com)" and pinging chat.so times out.

[image: Down for me or everyone?]

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ is "not loading" and pinging chat.so times out.

Comment: Could not duplicate.  Works fine for me.

Comment: and are we now back up?

Comment: happend to me too, working nice now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would love to blame Irene for this, but I fear we have to blame ourselves…

We recently made some major changes to the network architecture, and there are still a few things to iron out, especially when it comes to commuication between our two datacenters in Oregon (where chat is hosted) and New York (where the main sites come from). This was one of those things.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be this?

[image: Irene]

Comment: http://www.livestream.com/stackexchange -- doesn't look too bad :)

Comment: @balpha, can you [send Rovio outside](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/rovio-or-how-to-annoy-your-coworkers-from-200-miles-away/), controlled from Germany?

Comment: @Arjan Unfortunately the little guy can neither open doors, nor operate an elevator, nor will the radio connection cover the height distance of 26 floors...

Comment: Disappointing, @balpha! I was expecting signs [like this](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/horvitz/elevator_robot.htm) ;-)